# OR query in mongo_dart

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, querying

I want to write a validation check where the query should return all users with a given username "OR" a given email. How could I write such a query using the mongo_dart package without having to query all the data and check it manually?

example query: `if username=="x" or email=="y"`

The tried this using the below query, but it did not work.

```
List<dynamic> all = await coll2.find({
        "or": [
          {"username": username},
          {"email": email}
        ]
      }).toList();
```

Moreover, using `$or` instead of `or` is raising syntax error in dart.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
await coll2.find(
   where.eq('username', username).or(where.eq('email', email))
).toList();
```